# Compile XCode Projects online

Tags: iphone, c++

I'm using the mosync library for develop iPhone applications. It generates the Xcode project ,
now I need to compile it to make it run on a iphone. So for that I need a mac.

do anybody know somewhere online to find online compiler which do that with a web based interface?

--thanks in advance--

Comment: Like you said, you need a Mac.

Comment: Yes sir , the question is about a online accessible mac. Read the answer that I've marked accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its really a difficult ask, since apples terms of use on certificates stop people from doing this.

But I got a paid solution for the same problem you mentioned which provides Xcode on Macintosh with latest updates. It just cost about 10$-20$ per month. Initially, you will get the trial offer too. If you like it, then you can subscribe it.

But friends beware of those who provides hacintosh version.

You can refer to following link-

1. http://www.xcodeclub.com/
2. http://virtualmacosx.com/

Comment: its cheaper to buy a mac mini

Comment: I will suggest atleast you got a free trial and for occassional users its best...!!!

Comment: why downvoted ? His links are working still. Ya but it's cheaper to buy a mac mini.

Comment: @sandundhammika thanks for supporting me.
Atleast u check those links.
And my point of view is that people who just dont want to buy a mac for their first project can use these links.

Comment: anyway it's for enterprise work BTW. For learning purposes, I think it's better to buy a mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile C or C++ right on iPhone/iPad you can try [CppCode ios app](http://cppcode.info)